# "To take something from..." Vs. "To take something away from..." Vs. To take something off someone"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've heard these forms for the same purposes, and I'm not sure what's more natural since most of these speakers are not really native English speakers. Which of these are correct?

> **Friend**: Do you have the complete homework?
>
> **I**: Yes, I do. You can take it "off"/ "from" / "away from" me today afternoon.

The choices are:

> To take something from someone

vs.

> To take something away from someone

vs.

> To take something off someone"

Comment: In the future, try to avoid abbreviations such as "sth". Many learners (as well as native speakers) may be confused.

Answer (score 1):

To *take something away from someone* means to remove the thing from their grasp or control,  so that they can no longer wield it or use it.

> She took the scissors away from the toddler.
>
> The judge took his drivers license away for a year when he was found guilty of drunken driving.

To *take something from someone* can mean to receive it from them as they offer it to you, or to forcibly remove it from their grasp or control, similar to "take away".

To receive an offered item:

> She took a canape from the platter offered to her by the catering staff.
>
> Here, take this umbrella from me. I have an extra one in the car.

To remove forcibly:

> Mom!  Billy took my coloring book from me and he won't give it back.
>
> The State took their houses from them under eminent domain and demolished their neighborhood so that an automobile factory could be built there.

Comment: _Take something off someone_ is a colloquial way of saying _take it from them_ - except when it is meant literally, like taking a hat off their head.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "take" in "take it from them". Do you mean "obtain" or "wrest"?  If "obtain", I'm familiar with that colloquial usage of **off** in combination with "get" but not  with "take".  *How did you get your hands on those bootleg DVDs? -- I got them off Mike.*